# windows phone network trace

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a windows phone 8 app that authenticates to email using httpwebrequest. For some reason I'm getting an authentication error and I need to look at the traffic.

Is there a way to configure visual studio to see the raw http traffic when I debug from my phone?

For example, can I configure fiddler to look at the traffic?
Are there any tricks to print to console the httpwebrequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing with Visual Studio.
You can use Fiddler though. Just connect your device to the same WiFi as your PC, on the device Settings > Wifi > long tap on your network and tap Edit. Turn proxy on and type in your PC IP address and use 8888 as port. Open Fiddler and you are done. Remember to go to FIddler settings and allow the detection for remote devices:

Tools > Fiddler options > Connections > Allow remote computers to connect

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I try it, I can no longer connect using https. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Mozly HTTPS main purpose is to hide precious data behind an encryption, the fact that you can't see raw data doesn't amaze me. In short is not really possible, but it depends on the HTTPS certificate quality. (I'm not an expert in web security)

Comment: Its not impossible, I read that I can put some kind of root certificate but I dont know how to on the windows phone.

Comment: Never said it's impossible, but I'm not an expert of these things. I suggest you to open a different question since the topic is not the same as the first one.

Comment: I found that the best way to solve my problem was to create a mock server that echos the raw requests.